# Obtaining the include paths cpp searches

Tags: preprocessor, posix, c-preprocessor

How do I obtain the system include search paths of the C preprocessor? This is for a script that parses arbitrary source files and needs to know the full pathnames of the headers they #include. Let's ignore for a moment that the user can alter this sequence of search paths with compiler flags. I'd prefer a solution that uses standard tools found on POSIX systems so my script depends on next to nothing.

I tried:

```
cpp -v </dev/null | unusually_complex_filter
```

But this apparently doesn't take in account things like `$C{,PLUS}_INCLUDE_PATH`. To know where vector of `#include <vector>` is in, I suppose I must know the search paths in their precise order.

Comment: It seems that the cpp -v </dev/null output things like "--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4", does this help you question?

Comment: This varies by language (most notably C vs C++), depending on compiler.  How do you plan on dealing with projects that use a CPPFLAGS variable in a makefile?  What is the [purpose of your script?](http://tinyurl.com/meta-xy)

Answer (score 0):

The standard headers are not required to be accessible as regular files containing standard-compliant C source. Usually, they are accessible as files but use many extensions.

Perhaps you can run the preprocessor, which is accessible in a POSIX-compliant manner as `c99 -E`, on the source files and use its output. POSIX does not define the exact output of the preprocessor, but it usually contains special lines that show the origin of each actual line.

Answer (score 0):

with test.cpp like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **)
{
  return 0
}
```

and **cpp** from the gcc toolsuite you can call:

```
cpp test.cpp | grep '^#.*' | awk '{print $3}'
```

you will get

```
"test.cpp"
"<built-in>"
"<command-line>"
"test.cpp"
"/usr/include/c++/4.4/string"
"/usr/include/c++/4.4/string"
"/usr/include/c++/4.4/string"
"/usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h"    
"/usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h"
"/usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h"
```

and many more lines.

You will obviously get a lot of "duplicates", as many include files are included by other include files as well.

Answer (score 0):

After some [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/98013#98013) to get context, I think this question is just a misunderstanding of cpp for parsing different languages.

I don't know how portable -x is (or how portable -v's output format is, for that matter), though other compilers could have something very similar (I believe Intel's compiler behaves identically here, for example), but it seems you just need to tell cpp what language you're using for it to include it's language-dependent, internally-configured paths:

```
$ cpp --version  # my cpp is from gcc
cpp (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
...
$ cpp -v </dev/null 2>&1 1>/dev/null | sed -nr 's/^ ([^ ]+)$/\1/p'
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
/usr/include/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include
$ cpp -v -x c++ </dev/null 2>&1 1>/dev/null | sed -nr 's/^ ([^ ]+)$/\1/p'
/usr/include/c++/4.4
/usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
/usr/include/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

This dovetails nicely when your script takes project-specific include paths:

```
$ mkdir my-include  # or else cpp ignores it
$ cpp -Imy-include -v -x c++ </dev/null 2>&1 1>/dev/null | sed -nr 's/^ ([^ ]+)$/\1/p'
my-include
/usr/include/c++/4.4
/usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
/usr/include/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

The returned order is the order to search, however <> includes skip the paths for "" includes (but "" includes do search <> paths).  Here, cpp's output does distinguish the two sets of paths, if you need that.